# ServiceStack/NativeScript: Error saying "Cannot find name 'RequestMode'" for servicestack-client

Tags: typescript, servicestack, nativescript

I had the Groceries app working (NativeScript/Angular2) and then decided to replace some service calls with calls to a ServiceStack backend.

So, I followed some instructions on [ServiceStack.net](http://docs.servicestack.net/typescript-add-servicestack-reference). VSCode seemed to be happy, but when I do `tns run android` I get:

> Found peer TypeScript 2.2.2

> node_modules/servicestack-client/src/index.d.ts(245,11): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'RequestMode'.

> node_modules/servicestack-client/src/index.d.ts(246,18): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'RequestCredentials'.

I've been searching for what this is about, but havent gotten a clear answer, really. What puzzles me is this line I also see:

> Found peer TypeScript 2.2.2

but I have TypeScript 2.7.1 installed:
[image]

I suspected it had to do with the version of TypeScript, as I read this:

> The W3C fetch definitions are built into TypeScript 2.3+, if using older versions of TypeScript they can be installed with:
>
> npm install --save-dev @types/whatwg-fetch

which made things a lot worse:

[image]

Here is my package.json:

```js
{
  "description": "NativeScript Application",
  "license": "SEE LICENSE IN <your-license-filename>",
  "readme": "NativeScript Application",
  "repository": "<fill-your-repository-here>",
  "nativescript": {
    "id": "org.nativescript.Groceries",
    "tns-android": {
      "version": "3.4.1"
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~4.0.0",
    "email-validator": "^1.1.1",
    "nativescript-angular": "~3.0.0",
    "nativescript-social-share": "^1.5.0",
    "nativescript-theme-core": "~1.0.4",
    "reflect-metadata": "~0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "~5.2.0",
    "servicestack-client": "0.0.42",
    "tns-core-modules": "~3.0.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/whatwg-fetch": "0.0.33",
    "babel-traverse": "6.4.5",
    "babel-types": "6.4.5",
    "babylon": "6.4.5",
    "lazy": "1.0.11",
    "nativescript-dev-android-snapshot": "^0.*.*",
    "nativescript-dev-typescript": "^0.4.0",
    "typescript": "~2.2.1"
  }
}
```

and the `tsconfig.json`:

```js
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es5",
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "noEmitHelpers": true,
        "noEmitOnError": true,
        "lib": [
            "es6",
            "dom",
            "es2015.iterable"
        ],
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "*": [
                "./node_modules/tns-core-modules/*",
                "./node_modules/*"
            ]
        }
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "platforms",
        "**/*.aot.ts"
    ]
}
```

So, I'm not really sure what I installed or what the state of my modules/packages are, but I'm not sure how to resolve this.

### Update

A very strange thing just happened:

1. I had previously copied the `node_modules` out from my Groceries folder (into the parent folder) and done a `npm install` but it didn't help
2. I then `git clone` the Groceries app into a new folder
3. I then noticed that the new `git clone` was using the old, copied node_modules that wasn't even in the app folder (it was in the parent folder)
4. After I deleted the node_modules in the parent folder, the `git clone` version of Groceries started to work!

Anyway, how do I resolve these errors?